# Why are Java keywords invalid Android resource ids?

Tags: android, aapt

When adding a new View in a layout xml, I noticed that my build was failing when using the id `@+id/package` with the error message `error: invalid symbol: 'package'`. I then started experimenting and noticed that Java keywords such as `public`, `void`, `int`, etc. cause this error when aapt is running.

Why does this error occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource compiler turns your resource ids into fields of the class `R.id` (which you can see by looking in the `R.java` file that is automatically generated when the resources are compiled). Since it is illegal to use a Java keyword as a class field name, it is illegal to use a Java keyword as the name of a resource (be it an id, a layout, or anything else).

Note that for the same reason you cannot use a number as a resource name (e.g., you can't have a graphics file named "3.png"). All resource names must be valid Java identifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had no idea that there was any restrictions on resource file names.

Comment: @Carlo - Yeah, if that restriction is documented, I can't find it. But once you realize that every resource name becomes a field name in a Java class, it's obvious why the restriction is there.